# Android Hide SMS from Inbox

Tags: android, sms

I was wondering if there was someway to temporarily hide a SMS from being visible. For instance, if you wanted to hide(but not delete) the last 30 messages in your inbox

Comment: Are you asking for how to do it in code, in a custom SMS application or how to hide them in Android's default app?

Comment: in code. sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make your own application which would perform this task. 
Make a database and store the messages, delete it from android database. When you want to restore it, send an intent indicating a new message has came with its body and other attributes.